# what does `a factor of K-fold` mean in GPU-based training?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

From the book "Deep Learning and Convolutional Neural Networks for Medical Image Computing"

> As we learned about the current state of research on deep learning, I
>   was surprised to find that other investigators had used convolutional
>   neural networks, one type of deep learning, in the past [22, 23]. But
>   there seemed to be something different about the most recent crop of
>   deep learning algorithms. They routinely used GPU processing to
>   `accelerate training by as much as a factor of 40-fold`. They also used
>   multiple convolution layers and multiple data reduction layers.

does `40-fold` mean "K-Fold Cross-Validation"?

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer if it answered your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author here refers to a comparison between older and most recent implementations of deep learning algorithms regarding execution time (accelerating processing speed). It just means that *"they used GPUs and achieved x40 better execution time"*. It has nothing to do with K-Folds.